# Mongo Push - Why is only one object updated?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with the documents like this with 25 documents

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("<some id>"),
    "code" : "1111",
    "myArray" : ["Choocolate"]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("<some id>"),
    "code" : "2222"
    "myArray" : ["Choocolate"]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("<some id>"),
    "code" : "3333",
    "myArray" : ["Choocolate"]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("<some id>"),
    "code" : "4444",
    "myArray" : ["Choocolate"]
}
```

and so on

I want to add an item to an myArray only fore certain documents based on a condition. so I tried this

```
db.mycollection.update
({ "code":
        {
           "$nin": ["1111","2222"]
        },
        
        {
            $push: { "myArray": "Coffee" } 
        }
    
)
```

I expect 'Coffee' to be added to myArray in all documents except the ones with code 1111 or 2222. But only it is added to an array only in one document.

How to I add an item to anArray in multiple documents based on a condition against a field in a document?

Comment: user add `{ multi: true }` third parameter in update() function or alternate option use updateMany() instead of update()

Comment: Thank you. That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation update updates only a single element:

```
By default, the db.collection.update() method updates a single document. Include the option multi: true to update all documents that match the query criteria.
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

To update more use updateMany:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/